# How to add an id to an arraylist

Tags: android, json

I have a simple structure of the app, that just downloads some mysql data and displays it to a list view. The code snippet shows what I'm doing.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "centrActivity";

    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> randomCentr;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        parseJson();

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, randomTorgCentr);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    private ArrayList<String> parseJson() {
        randomCentr = new ArrayList<String>();

        JSONArray centr = null;

        //url
        String url = "";

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        Log.i(TAG, jsonObject.toString());
        try {
            torgCentr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("callback");
            Log.i(TAG, torgCentr.toString());
            for (int i=0; i<torgCentr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject o = torgCentr.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = o.getString("id");
                String name = o.getString("name");
                randomCentr.add(i, name);
                Log.i(TAG, randomTorgCentr.get(i));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return randomTorgCentr;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.i(TAG, randomCentr.get(position));
    }
}
```

Everything is displaying, but I have a problem. I have tables that are connected to this one by the id. I have only name attribute of the table in the list. So, how to specify for each element it's id from the json file, so I could make a new request, based on element's id and display the detailed data of the element??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create a model for your data and extend [`BaseAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) and create a collections of your models mapped to it. Another option would be to just create a simple `Map` and have the index as key and the id as the value. But I recommend you go with the first option.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `ArrayList` use `HashMap`. In HashMap you can store a key value pair. So in your case you can store a id and it's data accordingly

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've used hash map, but I had problems with displaying the data. Can you show me the code snippet or a link with a tutorial??

Comment: @PAcan there are plenty of tutorials out there.. try one .. post your code with what you have tried.. Then I may help you